# how to recover data splitted by split command

Tags: linux

I've got a few files that were split using the split command. Which command can combine them into one file again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cat.

```
cat partaa partab partac > file
```

Comment: Even better, the files created by split will be processed in the correct order if you say "`cat part* > file`"